# Improper Integration Step by Step

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, wolfram-alpha-queries

I am trying to obtain the step-by-step analysis of the integral $\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ { y }^{ 3 }{ e }^{ -\frac { y }{ N }  }dy }$ by calling Wolfram Alpha:

```
WolframAlpha["integrate ((y^3)*exp(-y/N)) from 0 to Infinity", 
 PodStates -> {"Input__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

However, I only get the option to see the step-by-step solution for the indefinite case:

[image]

Simply changing the integration limits, avoiding infinity, allows me to see the whole process:

```
WolframAlpha["integrate ((y^3)*exp(-y/N)) from 0 to 9999", 
 PodStates -> {"Input__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]

Why does this happen? **How can I see the whole step-by-step solution of this improper integral?**

Comment: Can you get the step-by-step solution in W|A?

Comment: Yes, without any problem actually

Comment: Your query in the OP didn't work for me.  I was wondering, What query actually worked?

Comment: Both work in Mathematica and Alpha (for the latter, just introduce the string enclosed by quotation marks)

Comment: I meant by "work" that it produced the answer you're asking for, that is, the step-by-step solution. Seems unlikely that it works: If it works for you in Mathematica, then why did you ask how to make it work in Mathematica? I thought if you shared what worked in W|A, then someone might be able to make it work in *M*. -- Seems Chip's partial answer might make the point moot, though.

Comment: Considering the production of the desired step-by-step solution, it worked in W|A, but not in Mathematica - hence the purpose of this question. Given Chip Hurst's answer, the problem has been solved, and now it can be produced in both W|A and Mathematica.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get the step by step solution to the improper integral when entered directly on W|A. Interesting that you do. Do you have Pro? (However, using "pi" instead of "N" works on W|A, like in Chip's answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated condition `Re[N] > 0` is tripping things up. A workaround for the time being is to substitute a concrete value for `N` and substitute back after the fact.

```
WolframAlpha[
  "integrate ((y^3)*exp(-y/pi)) from 0 to Infinity",
  {{"Input", 2}, "Content"}, 
  PodStates -> {"Input__Step-by-step solution"}
] /. "\[Pi]" -> "N"
```

[image]